# switch between desktop view and mobile view for Responsive Joomla Template

Tags: php, mobile, joomla, responsive-design, joomla3.0

I use responsive joomla template for my joomla website.

How can I do to make visitor can choose or switch between desktop view and mobile view when they visit using mobile device?

Sorry for my bad english. Hope you understand what I mean...
Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate css file and put all the css media query in that file and put the below code to **head** section of your template index file.

```
$fullsite = $_GET['fullsite'];
if ($fullsite == 1) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="media.css">';
}
```

Now use the this code for making a switcher.
you can put this  code to the footer section.

```
if ($fullsite == 0) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?fullsite=1">Mobile Site</a>';
}else{
    echo '<a href="index.php?fullsite=0">Full Site</a>';
}
```

I hope it will help you.